# Como fazer gráfico de colunas agrupadas usando ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Estou com dificuldade em fazer um gráfico de colunas agrupadas usando o pacote ggplot2.

Meus dados são os seguinte:

| Lat | Cu | Cr | Mn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | -0,86 | 2,85 | 1,25 |
| 14 | 5,16 | 19,51 | 14,60 |
| 13 | 2,51 | 10,59 | 6,87 |
| 12 | 1,87 | 8,23 | 6,92 |
| 11 | 2,05 | 9,66 | -0,51 |
| 10 | 5,26 | 8,46 | 2,79 |
| 9 | -0,37 | 2,78 | 0,94 |
| 8 | 2,37 | 8,85 | 7,07 |
| 7 | 3,68 | 9,31 | 5,70 |
| 6 | 3,64 | 13,42 | 9,19 |
| 5 | -0,75 | 2,23 | -0,97 |
| 4 | -0,05 | 3,48 | 0,70 |
| 3 | -0,37 | 2,92 | 0,24 |
| 2 | -0,84 | 2,67 | -0,50 |
| 1 | -0,73 | 2,94 | 0,61 |
| 0 | 1,32 | 6,72 | 2,69 |
| -1 | 2,50 | 8,53 | 53,70 |

E aqui segue o [exemplo de gráfico que desejo criar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaGwi.png)

Porém, no y eu quero as concentrações para os diferentes metais (Cu, Cr e Mn), enquanto que no x quero as latitudes (15:-1)

Obs.: Não vou deixar meu código aqui que tenho até vergonha T_T
Por favor, me ajudem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este tipo de problema geralmente está relacionado à reformatação dos dados. O formato deve ser longo e os dados estão em formato largo. Veja [esta postagem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) sobre como reformatar os dados do formato largo para o longo.

## R base

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
})

dados %>%
  pivot_longer(-Lat, names_to = "Coleta") %>%
  mutate(Lat = factor(Lat)) %>%
  barplot(value ~ Coleta + Lat, ., beside = TRUE, ylab = "",
          col = c(Cr = "#2e8b57", Cu = "#9acd32", Mn = "#4eee94"))
legend("top", legend = c("Cr", "Cu", "Mn"), 
       fill = c(Cr = "#2e8b57", Cu = "#9acd32", Mn = "#4eee94"), 
       box.col = NA, horiz = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Pacote `ggplot2`

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

dados %>%
  pivot_longer(-Lat, names_to = "Coleta") %>%
  mutate(Lat = factor(Lat)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Lat, value, fill = Coleta)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  ylab("") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Cr = "#2e8b57", Cu = "#9acd32", Mn = "#4eee94")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Dados

```r
dados <- "Lat   Cu  Cr  Mn
15  -0,86   2,85    1,25
14  5,16    19,51   14,60
13  2,51    10,59   6,87
12  1,87    8,23    6,92
11  2,05    9,66    -0,51
10  5,26    8,46    2,79
9   -0,37   2,78    0,94
8   2,37    8,85    7,07
7   3,68    9,31    5,70
6   3,64    13,42   9,19
5   -0,75   2,23    -0,97
4   -0,05   3,48    0,70
3   -0,37   2,92    0,24
2   -0,84   2,67    -0,50
1   -0,73   2,94    0,61
0   1,32    6,72    2,69
-1  2,50    8,53    53,70"
dados <- read.table(text = dados, header = TRUE,
                    dec = ",", colClasses = "numeric")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Funcionou!! sem palavras pela ajuda, entendi o meu erro e não o cometerei mais. :D Obrigada!

Comment: @AlineFaria não esqueça de votar a favor e se você julgar como a melhor resposta, marque-a como favorita.

Comment: @Rui Barradas, fiz algo semelhante à sua resposta. No entanto, na especificação do `geom_col(position = )` eu coloquei `geom_col(position = "dodge")`. Na sua resposta, reparei que vc usa o  `geom_col(position = position_dodge())`. Se for possível, poderias explicar a diferença?

Comment: @itamar `position_dodge()` é uma função que pode modificar vários elementos das barras, tais como a largura das barras ou o espaço entre elas. Só `"dodge"` é mais simples e neste caso faz exatamente a mesma coisa. Usei a forma mais complicada or questão de hábito, nada mais.